Count distinct using group by in R with a condition
I have a dataset containing teams, player names, and their scores:
dat <- data.frame(team = c("new", "new", "old"),
           player = c("bob", "bill", "sue"),
           score = c(1, 0, 3))

I would like to get a count of unique players with a score >= 1. This code works to get total distinct players by team:
dat %>% 
  group_by(team) %>%
  summarise(total_players = n_distinct(player))

However, as mentioned before, I would like to only count players with a score >= 1. I tried the code below but this is not working:
dat %>% 
  group_by(team) %>% 
  summarise(total_players = n_distinct(ifelse(score >= 1, player, NA)))

Note that the solution must be done within this group_by framework; I do not want to filter the dataframe prior the summarize statement.

dat |> summarize(total_players = n_distinct(player[score >= 1])), or if you want how many per team, dat |>  summarize(total_players = n_distinct(player[score >= 1]), .by = team)

Here there is an alternative using dplyr:
dat |> 
  group_by(team) |> 
  filter(score >= 1) |> 
  summarise(total_players = n_distinct(player))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  team  total_players
  <chr>         <int>
1 new               1
2 old               1


Edited after @Jon Spring note. Still, this one retains some sort of grouping and does not return just the count.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dat <- tibble::tibble(
  team = c("new", "new", "old", "old", "old"),
  player = c("bob", "bill", "sue", "bob", "bob"),
  score = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 1)
)

dat |> 
  mutate(cond = if_else(score >= 1, ">=1", "<1")) |> 
  distinct(player, cond) |> 
  count(cond)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   cond      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 <1        1
#> 2 >=1       2

# bill is also part of the count
dat <- tibble::tibble(
  team = c("new", "new", "old", "old", "old"),
  player = c("bob", "bill", "sue", "bob", "bob"),
  score = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1)
)

dat |> 
  mutate(cond = if_else(score >= 1, ">=1", "<1")) |> 
  distinct(player, cond) |> 
  count(cond)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   cond      n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 >=1       3

Created on 2024-04-10 with reprex v2.1.0

I don't think this does what OP intends. It counts how many different answers there are to the question "is the value >= 1?" i.e. if you change bill to 1 your result decreases to 1, even though that change should increase the "count of unique players with a score >= 1" as requested in OP.

why not? If I understood correctly, he needs the count of unique players for which the score is higher or equal to one. In my example, I have Bob who appears four times and has a score of >=1. Still, I get two as a result as he needs to be counted only once.

See my note above. If you change bill to score of 1 in your example data and run it again, that should increase the count of unique players >= 1, but in your code it will reduce the output, since you are actually counting the number of unique responses to the question "is the value >=1?". In your code, the answer is 2 when some are below 1 and others are >=1, since that's two different unique responses to the if_else test. But your answer will become 1 if all the scores are >= 1, which is not what the OP is looking for.

true! I didn't consider doing the counter proof. I have upvoted your answer!
